Prompt for username when starting wsl for the first time (like in Ubuntu)
We are creating a custom linux image for WSL based on RHEL and we want to create user when users login for the first time just like the ubuntu image.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
